# Gradle to identify which unit-tests to run on build

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, build, bazel

There's a big java codebase in Gradle with hundreds of sub-projects. Some sub-projects are independent (not in the main build graph), or child-projects. Even though I change java source code on those, Gradle runs all the tests available for all projects. Can Gradle identify whether to run or not unit-tests automatically?

If I have thousands of test and not enough resource, it is going to take a while.

I am also wondering how it is done in Google Bazel.

Comment: It can, provided you have access to a build cache. See this for more information: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html. Alternatively, you can opt to only run tests in the subprojects you've made changes in using something like `gradle :subproject-name:test`

Comment: In addition to the build cache, Gradle also has built-in up-to-date checking to ensure that tasks that don't need to be run (again) are skipped. Of cause, if you change make a change to a shared library, all projects depending on that library should be re-tested. But unrelated project should be skipped if they have previously been built and tested. If this is not the case for you, you probably have something in your build scripts that invalidates the up-to-date state.

Comment: Why do you think it is a problem to run thousands of unit tests? IMHO thousands of unit test should run in a matter of seconds.

Comment: @Jocke I wouldn't write here if it wasn't. Build servers run just on a few machines. Imagine, if everyone from thousands of devs start pushing new submits and each submit would trigger a full run? It is a real problem!

Comment: Bjørn Vester Where can I read about this in more details? I don't see this happening in our build servers.

Comment: I see. Here are two useful links https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks do you keep the build cache on the build server? If that is not the case then gradle will have no knowledge about the output from a task and you will end up running all the tests

Comment: Thanks for the links. Jocke, yes I keep.